# Google Sheets formulas that needs to read data from drop down boxes

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I am trying to create a master spreadsheet that is pulling information from several other sheets into this one master sheet.
I then plan on using this master sheet to pull statistics.
In the sign up sheets there are drop down boxes for `Yes`, `No`. My master sheet will pull all data except the `Yes`, `No` from the drop down boxes.

I can not figure out why!!

Comment: Welcome. Please share what you have tried so far. Even better, do read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: There is little we can tell you if we can't see what you are seeing. If you'd like, share a link to a copy of your sheet, clearly representing the problem and the goal. Be sure to set the link's Share permission to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor" when you create it. If there is sensitive information on the incoming form page, change any such data to realistic dummy data. That will be the most efficient and effective means for those here to provide help.